# Targeting Users for House Ads in Flurry

Tags: ads, flurry

I am trying to target Users for House Ads in Flurry. 
I have been told that currently keyword targeting is not supported for House Ads.
Can anyone tell me how can I target users.

Answer (score 1):

Two parts to using keyword targeting:

1. Set the keywords in the app
   for iOS

   ```
   NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ltv", nil];
   NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0", nil];
   NSDictionary *keywords = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];


   [FlurryAds setKeywordsForTargeting:keywords];
   [FlurryAds fetchAdForSpace:adSpace frame:self.view.frame size:FULLSCREEN];
   ```

or for Android

```
     Map<String, String> keywords = new HashMap<String, String>();

     keywords.put("ltv", "0");

     FlurryAds.setTargetingKeywords(keywords);
     FlurryAds.fetchAd(mContext, adSpace, adLayout, FlurryAdSize.FULLSCREEN);
```

2.Create the campaigns to target the users based on the keyword value, instructions provided here:
http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/GettingStarted/Targeting#campaigns.

In the Segment Targeting section provide the keywords and the values for which the campaign applies. 
For example, following the example above, if  would like to target the users whose ltv=0, you would enter that statement in Keywords section. Multiple keyword values are comma separate if the same house ad is to be served.

You can create multiple campaigns if you'd like to serve different ads based on the keyword value.